# How to show the details of any selected Record in mvc 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application and using single view to create and edit, After creating the record successfully it get render on Page.
But the issue is how to create details page and also having another issues is on that view having three tabs second and third tab having jqGrid. then how to show details of that jqGrid. I am not clear that for details page it is necessity to create new view for  details page.I stuck over there please suggest any suggestion for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MVC is a broad term, are we talking about Angular, ASP.NET, etc?

Comment: No not angular but it is ASP.net MVC 4 Razor application .

Comment: jqGird is only for CRUD operation and showing the table view. For the detail view. Create a partial view, in the tab where you want to show the detail view load that partialview over there with the MVC detail action to load the detail page.

Comment: If you need to show details without refreshing the page, submit the form using AJAX call to a controller, return data and update the view with javascript. Other aproach is refresh the entire page when submit the form showing all data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Partial View - Good Start

***Since there is no code present right now - I will use sample class names and Markup selectors.***

### Set Up Data

Say you have the following Data Entity Class:

```
public class DBItem
{
    [Key]
    public int DBItemID {get; set;}

    public string DBItemName {get;set;}

    public string DBItemDescription
}
```

Set in the DBContext like so:

```
public context : DbContext
{
    //STANDARD CONTEXT CODE OMITTED FOR SAKE OF BREVITY
    public DbSet<DBItem> DbItems {get;set;}
}
```

### Set Up Controller

We now need to set up an action result in the controller of your choice - we will use **HomeController** in this example.

Your controller must get the items from the database to populate the partial view:

```
public HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult DBItemPartialView(int itemID)
    {
        DBItem model = new context().DBItems.Where(row => row.DBItemID == itemID).First();
        return PartialView(model); 
        //IF THE VIEW NAME IS NOT THE SAME AS THE ACTION NAME
        //YOU NEED TO PASS THE VIEW NAME AND THE MODEL
    }

}
```

### Set Up View

Populate a partial view with the data that you just passed.

***DBItemPartialView.cshtml:***

```
@model yourProject.Models.DBItem


<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.DBItemID</td>
            <td>@Model.DBItemName</td>
            <td>@Model.DBItemDescription</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

### Call Your Partial View Using JQuery

You can now populate an html element with your partial view using JQuery

- You don't have to do a complete page refresh.
- Get new data on the fly.

#### JS

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#myBtn', function () {

        var id = 1;

        $('#myDiv').load("/Home/DBItemPartialView", {itemID: 1});

    });
});
```

#### Markup

*Let's assume that you use bootstrap for this exercise:*

```
<div class='container'>

    <!-- WHATEVER CONTENT YOU WANT -->
    <div class='row'>
        <button id='myBtn' class='btn btn-primary'>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class='row'>
        <div id='myDiv' class='col-md-10 col-md-offset-1'>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Hope this helps. Be more specific and show your code if you need more specific answers.*

*Happy Coding*